# Need Excel formula to Merge duplicate rows value with one column as unique value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please find the below table,
[Values in a Column A,B,C ---> OutPut :D[image: **][1]**]
Colum A contains duplicate row but based on column B I need to concatenate the column c value with delimiter as comma.
Kindly suggest the formula for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have come up a way for you to achieve your goal but you will need to add a helper column (I called it `Output (Pre-processed)` which is at `column D`).  You can hide it if you don't want to see that column.  See the attached pic below.  **`Column E`** is the output you want.

[image]

Formula at `Cell D2`:

```
=IF(OR(ROW(D1)=1,MAX(--($A$1:A1=A2)*--($B$1:B1=B2)*ROW($A$1:A1))=0),C2,INDEX($D$1:D1,MAX(--($A$1:A1=A2)*--($B$1:B1=B2)*ROW($A$1:A1)))&", "&C2)
```

Formula at `Cell E2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$B$1:B2,B2)=1,INDEX($D$2:$D$8,MATCH(MAX(--($B$1:$B$8=B2)*(LEN($D$1:$D$8))),LEN($D$2:$D$8),0)),"Duplicate row-Not Required")
```

In my pic, I also showed you highlighted `columns F to H` and those are for your reference where how I processed through the logic.  `column F` is the return of last appeared row number so I can then concatenate on `column G`.  `Column H` is to find the max length of the output for the `INDEX/MATCH` on `column E` and this way I can show the outcome on the first record instead of last one.

Try and let me know.